# How to Upgrade projects in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, project, android-4.2-jelly-bean

We created an android application using eclipse in the version of Froyo until jelly bean 4.2.0 the problem is, we want to run the application in Jelly bean 4.2.2 ..I tried upgrading the minSdkVersion and the targetSdkVersion in eclpise still the application crush when I tried it in 4.2.2 my API .I also go to Windows>preferences>android >the platform has already 4.2.2

I am asking for help..please Help!!

Answer (score 0):

In manifest change "android:sdkVersion" to 17

Comment: In uses-sdk tag, change android:targetSdkVersion to 17

Comment: what do you mean by sdkVersion? this one 
android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17"

If this is what you mean,I already change it

Comment: When I run the application it says : unfortunately,Javac101(the name of the app)has stopped..

Answer (score 0):

Update target to latest one in project.properties file also.